# how to check if objdump disassembles a binary file for the correct architure?

Tags: arm, binaryfiles, armv7, objdump

I would like to disassemble armv7m executable using the command `arm-none-eabi-objdump -d -S -marm my_elf_file.elf`  ..i got this output

```
file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .init:

00008000 <_init>:
    8000:   b5f8        push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
    8002:   bf00        nop
    8004:   bcf8        pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7}
    8006:   bc08        pop {r3}
    8008:   469e        mov lr, r3
    800a:   4770        bx  lr

Disassembly of section .text:

0000800c <_GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN9__gnu_cxx9__freeresEv>:
    800c:   b538        push    {r3, r4, r5, lr}
    800e:   f44f 651e   mov.w   r5, #2528   ; 0x9e0
    8012:   4c07        ldr r4, [pc, #28]   ; (8030 <_GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN9__gnu_cxx9__freeresEv+0x24>)
    8014:   4628        mov r0, r5
    8016:   60e5        str r5, [r4, #12]
    8018:   f005 fbe6   bl  d7e8 <malloc>
    801c:   60a0        str r0, [r4, #8]
    801e:   b120        cbz r0, 802a <_GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN9__gnu_cxx9__freeresEv+0x1e>
    8020:   2300        movs    r3, #0
    8022:   6060        str r0, [r4, #4]
    8024:   6005        str r5, [r0, #0]
    8026:   6043        str r3, [r0, #4]
    8028:   bd38        pop {r3, r4, r5, pc}
    802a:   60e0        str r0, [r4, #12]
    802c:   6060        str r0, [r4, #4]
    802e:   bd38        pop {r3, r4, r5, pc}
    8030:   000228b4    .word   0x000228b4
```

how to make sure that the  disassembly generated is for armv7m and not another arm architure ?

Comment: you cant really, necessarily the gnu disassembler is going to disassemble whatever it finds, data, text, etc as well as code.  the elf file can/does contain hints for the tool to know arm vs thumb instructions likewise with the variable length  nature of thumb2 which in general means you cannot rely on disassembly output (just look at x86 output even with gnu, it is only sometimes usable, trivial to confuse, as expected)

Comment: the arm-whatever-whatever has access to all of the arm/thumb instructions and will use that.  aarch64-whatever-whatever is going to be limited to that isa and no room for confusion with the arm/thumb instruction sets (aarch32).

Comment: it is trivial for example to embed thumb2 code in a binary that only supports thumb and then binutils will disassemble the thumb2 instruction vs one/two undefines...